# Error inflating a ListView

Tags: android, listview, fragment, android-arrayadapter, android-inflate

I have a class that extends from a Faragment, called Agenda. Its layout has a listView, but I get an error when infating the view this class returns to the main activity. Here is the error and code:

```
> 03-11 13:50:55.553  29007-29007/com.example.ixtilion.proyecto E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ixtilion.proyecto, PID: 29007
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ixtilion.proyecto/com.example.ixtilion.proyecto.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.ixtilion.proyecto.Agenda.onCreateView(Agenda.java:25)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.ixtilion.proyecto.Agenda.onCreateView(Agenda.java:25)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:228)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:469)
            at android.content.res.XResources.getTextArray(XResources.java:725)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getTextArray(TypedArray.java:629)
            at android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.getTextArray(XResources.java:1076)
            at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:151)
            at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:142)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.ixtilion.proyecto.Agenda.onCreateView(Agenda.java:25)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Agenda class:

```
 public class Agenda extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_agenda, container, false);

            String[] values = new String[] { "holA", "prueba" };

            final ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
                items.add(values[i]);
            }



            ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , items));

            return view;
           // View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_agenda, container, false);
            //return rootView;
        }
    }
```

And here is the XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="CONTACTOS"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:entries="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I think the error is in the ListView element... because I still get the error even if I remove the ArrayAdapter code

Comment: try  `list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , items));`. My comment just like Playing chess in a dark

Comment: try to remove the line 'android:entries="@android:color/darker_gray"', this is wrong and you are already setting an adapter in code

Comment: What is line 25 in `Agenda.java` ?

Answer (score 1):

you should remove `android:entries="@android:color/darker_gray"` from your layout xml file.
you setting listview items in an adapter dynamically.